# Send freeform email notification to manually entered recipient address

Tags: plugin-freeform

I'm trying to build a "send this page to a friend" form in Freeform. My code looks like this:

```
{% set form = craft.freeform.form("emailToAFriend") %}

{{ form.renderTag({returnUrl: "contact/success"}) }}

    {% if form.hasErrors %}
        <div class="freeform-form-has-errors">
            {{ "There was an error submitting this form"|t }}
        </div>
    {% endif %}

    {% set recipientsName = form.get("recipientsName") %}
    {% set recipientsEmail = form.get("recipientsEmail") %}
    {% set yourName = form.get("yourName") %}
    {% set yourEmail = form.get("yourEmail") %}
    {% set sharedUrl = form.get("sharedUrl") %}
    {% set message = form.get("message") %}

    <label>{{ yourName.label }}</label>
    <input name="{{ yourName.handle }}" value="{{ yourName.value }}" />
    {{ yourName.renderErrors() }}

    <label>Your Email Address</label>
    <input name="yourEmail" />
    {{ form.get("yourEmail").renderErrors() }}

    <label>{{ recipientsName.label }}</label>
    <input name="{{ recipientsName.handle }}" value="{{ recipientsName.value }}" />
    {{ recipientsName.renderErrors() }}

    <label>Their Email Address</label>
    <input name="recipientsEmail" />
    {{ form.get("recipientsEmail").renderErrors() }}

    {{ message.renderLabel() }}
    {{ message.renderInput() }}
    {{ message.renderErrors() }}

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>

{{ form.renderClosingTag }}
```

How could I get the field in `recipientsEmail` to pass to that recipient and choose the template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `recipientsEmail` field should be an `Email` fieldtype, and in Composer you need to set the notification template in the **Field Property Editor** column (on right) for that field and it'll send an email to the email that is entered in that field when the form is submitted. :)

View the documentation page here for more information about email notification options:
https://solspace.com/craft/freeform/docs/email-notifications/

Comment: Gah, I didn't realize I could do that! Thanks!